# Add date to sqlserver in yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

When i add the  lastImportedDate(dd-mm-yyyy) with the following method to the sql server everything is fine. In the database the date is yyyy-mm-dd

But add the lastImportedDate(dd-mm-yyyy) with a different pc on the same server the day and month are switched. In the database the date is yyyy-dd-mm.

```
internal static void insertSelloutSales(string CustomerID, string type, DateTime lastImported, string periodStart, string periodEnd)
{
     // Create SQL connection #connection
     SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(Connection.connectionString());
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

     string periodstartQuery = periodStart;
     string periodEndQuery = periodEnd;

     // Create query with values and execute query
     if (!periodStart.Equals("NULL"))
     {
         periodstartQuery = " '" + periodStart + "'";
     }

     if (!periodEnd.Equals("NULL"))
     {
         periodEndQuery = " '" + periodEnd + "'";
     }

     cmd.CommandText = "Insert into CarsSellout (CustomerID, type, lastImportedDate, PeriodStart, PeriodEnd) VALUES ('" + CustomerID + "', '" + type + "', '" + lastImported + "', " + periodstartQuery + ", " + periodEndQuery + ")";
     cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
     sqlConnection1.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     sqlConnection1.Close();
}
```

Note that the date settings on the pc's are both set as dd-mm-yyyy.

if you need more info please add a comment.!

What can be the problem in this case?

Comment: what do you mean by `in database the date is yyyy-dd-mm`?

Comment: Parameters of your method `periodStart` and `periodEnd` are strings. Change to `datetime`. Also change types of columns in database from `varchar` to `datetime`.

Comment: a) your data should be stored in the database as a date field, not as text; b) *please* use parameterized SQL. It may well fix this problem, and it will also protect you from SQL injection attacks. Never, never, never build SQL like this.

Comment: Date formatting is culture sensitive. Try using a specific CultureInfo, like en-US or Invariant. Another option is to explicitly format your date with ToString("yyyyMMdd") or such.

Comment: @SvenL: There's no reason to use string formatting at all, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet Agreed, using parameterbinding would be a much better option. But seeing the code that would be a whole new chapter for this person. But you are right, should have mentioned that.

Comment: Thank you all for the input. I'll learn parameterized SQL ASAP! @GiorgiNakeuri The date where the problem is about is allready a DateTime, and in my database the type is date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do **not** insert your `DateTime` values with their string representations. Add your `DateTime` values directly to your parameterized queries.

SQL Server keeps your `DateTime` values in a binary format. They didn't have *any* format or something. What you saw them as `yyyy-MM-dd` or `dd-MM-yyyy` are just their *textual* representations.

Generating different string representations of a `DateTime` instance for different servers *usually* because they use different culture settings. But since you didn't show any relevant code that generates your strings, we never know.

Speaking of, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Please read carefully;

- [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

As a best practice, use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections and commands automatically instead of calling `Close` methods manually.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = con.CrateCommand())
{
    // Define your CommandText with parameterized query.
    // Define your parameters and their values. Add them with Add method to your command
    // Open your connection
    // Execute your query
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer, i will keep it in mind.!

Comment: @JP..t Good to hear it.